# Google-plus integration in fragment

Tags: android, fragment, google-plus

I'm implementing google plus in fragment. When i clicked on login with google plus button then a pop-up comes choose account , after that nothing happens. But when i open my app again then it says user is connected and opened a new activity without even clicking on login button.

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements  ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

```
EditText username, email, password, cnfrmpswd;
protected static final ServiceConnection ServiceConnection = null;
Drawable myDrawable;
private LoginButton loginBtn;
//private TextView username;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Other other;




private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;



private static final String TAG = "Fragment1";

private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;

private boolean mIntentInProgress;

private boolean mSignInClicked;

private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
private ImageView imgProfilePic;
private TextView txtName, txtEmail;
private RelativeLayout rlProfileLayout, frag;

private Context mContext;
private Activity mActivity;


private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), statusCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mActivity = getActivity();
    mContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();





}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment1, container, false);

    username = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    email = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    password = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    cnfrmpswd = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    frag = (RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.frag1);


    imgProfilePic = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
    btnSignIn = (SignInButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnRevokeAccess = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
    btnSignOut = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);


    rlProfileLayout = (RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rlProfileLayout);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(rootView.getContext())
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API,PlusOptions.builder().build())
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();


    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            signInWithGplus();

        }
    });

    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signOutFromGplus();
        }
    });


    loginBtn = (LoginButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    loginBtn.setFragment(this);
    loginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
    loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
            if (user != null) {



                Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, GoogleMapActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
```

Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

```
             } 
            }
        });
    return rootView;
}
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {

           onSessionStateChange(session,state,exception);
}

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

};

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}



@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}


    private void resolveSignInError() {
          try {

             mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), RC_SIGN_IN);
             mIntentInProgress = true;

         } catch (SendIntentException e) {
             Log.e(TAG, "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
             mIntentInProgress = false;
             mGoogleApiClient.connect();
         }

        }

    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
         GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), mActivity,
                 0).show();
         return;
     }


     if (!mIntentInProgress) {
         // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
         mConnectionResult = result;

         if (mSignInClicked) {
             // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
             // resolve all
             // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
             resolveSignInError();
         }
     }

 }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode1, int resultCode1, Intent data1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode1, resultCode1, data1);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode1, resultCode1, data1);


        if (requestCode1 == Fragment1.RC_SIGN_IN) {
             if (resultCode1 != TabActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                 mSignInClicked = false;
             }

             mIntentInProgress = false;

             if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                 mGoogleApiClient.connect();
             }
         }
    }

     @Override
     public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
         mSignInClicked = false;
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         // Get user's information
            getProfileInformation();

         // Update the UI after signin
         updateUI(true);

     }

     @Override
     public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
         mGoogleApiClient.connect();


         updateUI(false);
     }

 private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
     if (isSignedIn) {


         btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         loginBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         username.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         cnfrmpswd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         rlProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     } else {
         rlProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         username.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         email.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         password.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         cnfrmpswd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         loginBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
 }



 private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);


            personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

            new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
```

}

```
        /**
          * Sign-in into google
          * */
         private void signInWithGplus() {
             if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                 mSignInClicked = true;                  
                 resolveSignInError();
             }
         }


         /**
          * Sign-out from google
          * */
         private void signOutFromGplus() {
             if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                 Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                 mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                 mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                 updateUI(false);
             }
         }

     private void revokeGplusAccess() {
         if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
             Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
             Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status arg0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "User access revoked!");
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: please provide some sample code of what you did so users can help you better understand what you did and which was the problem!

Comment: I have posted my code now. When i clicked on login button then nothing goes happen, but when i re-open my app, then it moves to another activity automatically and says you have logged in with google plus.